# Substring sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

The following query would return

```
PR-2014-00006-02
```

Query:

```
select PRItemNo 
from tPRItem
order by PRItemNo ASC
```

I want to sub string such as I will return the following result

```
col1   col2   col3    col4 
PR     2014   00006   02
```

Comment: I tried the following      select substring(PRItemNo,charindex('-',PRItemNo)+1,len(PRItemNo)-charindex('-',PRItemNo)),PRItemNo from tPRItem

Comment: what do you have as entry/data is it one column having `PR-2014-00006-02` as data or what ?

Comment: I has data PR-2014-00006-02 i want them to substring so that all values are in a seperrate column

Answer (score 4):

Use **[PARSENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx)**

```
   --Using PARSENAME 
   SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(PRItemNo ,'-','.'),4) col1, 
          PARSENAME(REPLACE(PRItemNo ,'-','.'),3) col2, 
          PARSENAME(REPLACE(PRItemNo ,'-','.'),2) col3, 
          PARSENAME(REPLACE(PRItemNo ,'-','.'),1) col4
   FROM Table1
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/178db/1)**

---

*Output*

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    COL4
PR      2014    00006   02
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t VARCHAR(30)= 'PR-2014-00006-02'
SELECT SUBSTRING(@t,CHARINDEX(@t,'-'),3),
SUBSTRING(substring(@t, charindex('-',@t) + 1,len(@t) - charindex('-',@t)),0,CHARINDEX('-',@t)+2),
RIGHT(substring(@t, charindex('-',@t) + 1,len(@t) - charindex('-',REVERSE(@t))-CHARINDEX('-',@t)),5),
 REVERSE(LEFT(reverse(@t), charindex('-', reverse(@t)) - 1))
```